# How to integrate OpenStreet Map in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, openstreetmap

I need to integrate OpenStreet Map in my c# application, as I have done some research work on google and bing and realized their licensing restrctions.
Now I want integrate OpenStreet Map

Tasks to accomplish:
1. Display Map and the vehicle location on the map.
2. Allow the user to define regions or radius on the map by drawing lines or shapes(triangles, rectange or circles) on the map and get the exact calculated long/lat, radius, distance etc

I am totally new to this area have no idea, trying hard to get the knowledge but due to time constraint i am having difficulties.

Appreicate if some body can share their experience and guide me to the right direction with blogs, samples etc.

Thanks

Comment: I would use OpenLayers (http://openlayers.org/). Not a c# code(javascript), but you can display it easily in a webBrowser control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're definitely looking for [GMap.NET](https://github.com/judero01col/GMap.NET). You can use any map provider, just take care of license restrictions as you already noted. Look at the example they provide, it'll be useful for you.

Comment: do you think that I can achieve both functionalities by using GMAP.NET

Comment: @Shax Yes. Look at the demo of GMap: you can easily add markers (your vehicle locations) and it's possible to draw shapes. I think it's the best open source library you'll find on the web for a winforms application.

Comment: You can hook in your own database as well, so this means you can add your own data/ Pologons/ Directions

Comment: Link is dead, I think this is the new one https://github.com/judero01col/GMap.NET

Comment: Though the question was long ago, I have recently been busy looking for a solution, and found a very suitable solution at https://github.com/AlexanderKrutov/WinFormsMapControl/ . Very simple and works perfectly.